# PHP session params secure and httpOnly

Tags: php, security, session

My sysadmin made a scan and told me that I should activate the `secure` parameter for PHP sessions (the site is using HTTPS).

We found that people also used `httpOnly` at the same time, but that seems to be a bit contradictory.  What should I do? Activate both, or only `secure`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely best practice to set both flags.

**Secure** means that client web browser will send back to server cookie with session id only if https protocol is used.

**HttpOnly** means that client browser will block access to cookie from JavaScript. It protects your users from session stealing (ie. in case you have an XSS vulnerability on your website).

Comment: Thanks. I thought httpOnly meant "no https".

Answer (score 1):

httponly has nothing (well for the most part) to do with whether or not you are using https...yes you should enable both. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly for more info on httponly.

Comment: Thanks for this nice link. I should really spend more time on owasp

Comment: owasp has a lot of solid info often backed up with case studies, it should definitely be on your to-read list ;)